# GluonConnect JSON converter cannot convert object

Tags: json, jax-rs, gluon-mobile

On the client app I have this POJO

```
public class Chicken {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Chicken(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and I run this

```
RestClient get = RestClient.create().method("GET")
        .host("http://localhost:8080/DevCrowd")
        .path("resources/chickens");
GluonObservableList<Chicken> sample = DataProvider.retrieveList(
        get.createListDataReader(Chicken.class));
System.out.println(sample);
```

But I get the error:

```
WARNING: Failed to create object of type class com.devcrowd.test.Chicken from the following json object {"id":1,"name":"AAA","age":12}
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.gluonhq.notesapp.Chicken
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter.readFromJson(JsonConverter.java:111)
    at com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonIterableInputConverter.next(JsonIterableInputConverter.java:108)
    at com.gluonhq.connect.provider.DataProvider.lambda$retrieveList$21(DataProvider.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.gluonhq.notesapp.Chicken.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 6 more
```

On the server I have this entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="all", query = "SELECT c FROM Chicken C")
public class Chicken {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Chicken() {}

    public Chicken(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and this service:

```
@Path("chickens")
public class ChickensResource {

    @Inject
    ChickenService cs;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String chickens() {
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        List<Chicken> chickens = cs.getAllChickens();
        chickens.stream().map(chicken -> Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("name", chicken.getName())
            .add("age", chicken.getAge())
            .build())
            .forEach(jsonArrayBuilder::add);
        return jsonArrayBuilder.build().toString();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void save(JsonObject chicken) {
        String name = chicken.getString("name");
        int age = chicken.getInt("age");
        cs.save(new Chicken(name, age));
    }
}
```

I can POST correctly (I check the DB and what I POST is there so this is why the error stack has a `Chicken` object ready) but I can't read it back. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/javadoc/1.4.3/com/gluonhq/connect/converter/JsonConverter.html#readFromJson-javax.json.JsonObject-) for `JsonConverter::readFromJson`:

> Convert the provided JSON Object into a Java object. If a new instance could not be created from the specified targetClass in the constructor, then null will be returned.
>
> The conversion works by inspecting all the property methods of the target class. A property method is any field that has both a getter and a setter method.

Now if you check your exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.gluonhq.notesapp.Chicken
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
```

the reason becomes clear: the target class (`com.gluonhq.notesapp.Chicken`) can't be instantiated, because it looks for a parameterless constructor.

All you'll need to do is add one:

```
public class Chicken {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Chicken() { }

    public Chicken(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    } 
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

The `DataProvider` returns an observable list, and you should use the `initializedProperty()` to find out when the list is ready, so you can get its content:

```
RestClient get = RestClient.create().method("GET")
            .host("http://localhost:8080/DevCrowd")
            .path("/resources/chickens");

GluonObservableList<Chicken> sample =  DataProvider.retrieveList(
           get.createListDataReader(Chicken.class));

sample.initializedProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
    if (nv) {
        for (Chicken chicken : sample) {
            System.out.println(chicken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes the error message but now I get an empty list `[]` instead of one with objects in it. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you actually creating a JSON response in your GET method? See the Cloudlink-rest-connector [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/cloudlink-rest-connector/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/samples/cloudlink/connector/rest/handler/ListHandler.java#L83)

Comment: I updated the code with something that returns a JSON array like in the example. I still get `[]`.  BTW that example doesn't run for me. i had a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745062/how-to-run-the-cloudlinkrestconnector-on-a-javaee7-sa) if you are interested.

Comment: Sorry but I want to get this to work finally. Any idea? I looked at RestClient example and at the cloudlink-rest-connector example and I don't see what i did differently.

Comment: Can you post your project (GitHub,...), so I can test it?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://github.com/omega09/RestExample). DevCrowd is the server .war which is more or less created by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWcoiXNoKxk) tutorial on YT. RestTest is a super simple client which i chopped down from a more feature full example. I should mention that the problem appears to be with the client because if i do the GET request with the browser I get the correct list. I just never get a correct response from either POST or GET with Gluon Connect (though the POST does add the object properly). Thanks again!

Comment: I've got your GET request working. You were missing the "observable" part. I'll edit my answer to include the small required fix.

Comment: Oh wow. Great! Didn't realize that's how the `GluonObservable...` works. I would recommend that the docs would say something about that. I realize now that because the call is asynchronious (and the printing too) the print happened before the object was added. I added a Thread.sleep between the call and the print as a way to simulate a listener and got some meaningful results as well. Looking at the GluonConnectRestprovider example the GluonObservableList is added directly to a ListView (that holds an ObservableList) which I guess is why it works without the added listener code. Thanks again!